# Android UI app Flow to code generator

Tags: android, java, gui-builder, user-interface

I'm looking for a solution free/paid that would allow the following.

- Create set of Drag and Drop UI Templates.
- Where each UI template visually represents an existing Fragment's
  layout.
- I need to be able to rearrange these dropped templates to adjust the
  flow of the onBoarding sequence.
- They need to have editable text fields for the fragments string or
  int variables
- Export the flow and generate a text array of code in the oder of the
  arranged flow

.[image]

So the output of the flow above would be something like this;

```
addFragment(FragmentIntro.newInstance("Some title",
            "Some subtitle explaining the purpose of this sequence",
            R.raw.a_drawable));

addFragment(FragmentMultipleChoice.newInstance(R.drawable.ic_some_other_drawable, 
            "Multiple Choice 1", 
            "Multiple Choice 2", 
            "Multiple Choice 3", 
            "Multiple Choice 4", 
            "Multiple Choice 3")); // the correct answer

addFragment(FragmentTrueFalse.newInstance(R.drawable.she_is_eating_salad,
            "She is eating a salad", 
            "True", 
            "False", 
            "True",)); // the correct answer
```

I've searched various tools. Vaadin, Proto, Adobe XD etc. but this seems pretty simple..Even PP would work, but that means having to use Powerpoint..
I am wondering if anyone knows of a tool simple enough to do this.
Thanks in advance